# How to select a photo from the photo table for each post by query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlcommand

I have two table I want to show one photo for every post but when the run query show post for every photo

Photo table :

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|  photo_id   |    post_id    |    photo_name                |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|     1       |        1      |    flower.jpg                |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|     2       |        1      |    book.jpg                  |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|     3       |        2      |    pen.jpg                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|     4       |        3      |    man.jpg                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|     5       |        3      |    women.jpg                 |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|     6       |        3      |    boy.jpg                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Post table :

```
+--------------------------------+
|  post_id    |   post_title     |
+--------------------------------+
|     1       |   flower         |
+--------------------------------+
|     2       |   book           |
+--------------------------------+
|     3       |   pen            |
+--------------------------------+
|     4       |   man            |
+--------------------------------+
|     5       |   women          |
+--------------------------------+
|     6       |   boy            |
+--------------------------------+
```

use flowing SQL Query and INNER JOIN but my result show like this :

```
SELECT
Photo.photo_name,
Post.post_title
FROM Photo
INNER JOIN Post
ON Photo.post_id = Post.post_id 
ORDER BY Post.post_id
```

Result Query after execute :

```
+-----------------------------+
|  post_title |   photo_name  |
+-----------------------------+
|     flower  |  flower.jpg   |
+-----------------------------+
|     flower  |  flower.jpg   |
+-----------------------------+
|     book    |  book.jpg     |
+-----------------------------+
|     book    |  book.jpg     |
+-----------------------------+
|     pen     |  pen.jpg      |
+-----------------------------+
|     pen     |  pen.jpg      |
+-----------------------------+
|     man     |  man.jpg      |
+-----------------------------+
|     man     |  man.jpg      |
+-----------------------------+
|     women   |  women.jpg    |
+-----------------------------+
|     women   |  women.jpg    |
+-----------------------------+
|     boy     |  boy.jpg      |
+-----------------------------+
|     boy     |  boy.jpg      |
+-----------------------------+
```

I have 6 posts in post table and I want to get one photo for every post but my result show post by photo count

Comment: You query and data don't match.  Photo 6 is showing to relate to Post 3, yet your results show it against Post 6 *(which actually has no photo associated to it according to your data)*.  Please show the ***actual*** contents of the tables - That's the likely source of your duplication.

Comment: i wonder how he get that result with the data and query examples @MatBailie https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eo5kTSwyQqmNKCc6cURtY8/0

Comment: @RaymondNijland - That data with that query ***can't*** generate that result.  Yet the OP has accepted an answer without correcting the contradictions.  May the gods of "attention to detail" be merciful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group by`. Since you have not defined, which photo to use in case of multiple photos for a post, we can get `Max()` photo for a post:

```
SELECT
MAX(Photo.photo_name),
Post.post_title
FROM Photo
INNER JOIN Post
ON Photo.post_id = Post.post_id 
GROUP BY Post.post_id, Post.post_title 
ORDER BY Post.post_id
```

Comment: This may simply be a method to hide the fact that what the OP ***thinks*** is in the tables is not what is ***really*** in the tables.  Until the OP clarifies what's really in the tables, and what should be in the tables, fixing the tables may be the correct approach *(rather than wasting complexity and server resources to hide the underlying problem)*

Comment: @MatBailie why cant a post have multiple photos. To me, it looks like a normal usecase.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - I'm not saying they can't.  I'm saying the the table contents that you've shown ***don't*** relate to the results you've shown.  If you want a reliable solution show the ***actual*** contents of the table and the ***actual*** results they generate.  At present your question directly contradicts itself.

Comment: @MatBailie I am not OP :-)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya - Good point :) Hopefully my point is still clear; this solves an assumed problem, where as the OP's self contradictory question ***may*** be better solved by fixing the data.  I'll go sit in a corner and hide for a while now.

Comment: @T3RON Are you sure your table does not contain duplicated data because if i execute your example data and query https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eo5kTSwyQqmNKCc6cURtY8/0 i can't reproduce your results..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want all post with at least one photo (I don't know which one). So, i would do `LEFT JOIN` with subquery :

```
SELECT pst.post_title, p.photo_name
FROM Post pst LEFT JOIN 
     Photo p
     ON p.post_id = pst.post_id AND 
        p.photo_id = (SELECT MAX(p1.photo_id)
                      FROM Photo p1
                      WHERE p1.post_id = p.post_id
                     );
```